# Setting Description property in XAML - ParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, linegraph, dynamic-data-display

I use D3 DynamicDataDisplay for my chart needs but when I try to setup Legend description for `LineGraph` element it gives me error:

```
The TypeConverter for "Description" does not support converting from string
```

Ok, but how to set this up?
I tried that:

```
<d3:LineGraph DataSource="{Binding Path=AvgWaitingTimes}" Stroke="Blue"
              Description="Some description"/>
```

It gives the error I wrote.
I also tried this:

```
<d3:LineGraph DataSource="{Binding Path=AvgConnectedTimes}" Stroke="Green">
    <d3:ViewportElement2D.Description>
        ??
    </d3:ViewportElement2D.Description>
</d3:LineGraph>
```

Problem is that there is nothing I can put instead of `??`. How to deal with it?
The library is really great but I stucked on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Funny, sometimes writing question on SO results in finding the answer very quickly by myself :]

It seems second code is ok, you just have to add:

```
<d3:PenDescription DescriptionString="Description is great!"/>
```

I have no idea why I haven't noticed it before.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <d3:ChartPlotter>
        <d3:LineGraph Stroke="Green" x:Name="line">
            <d3:ViewportElement2D.Description >
                <d3:PenDescription DescriptionString="Test"/>
            </d3:ViewportElement2D.Description>
        </d3:LineGraph>
    </d3:ChartPlotter>
```